# PayPal API payments wthout sign in, and obtaining an access token

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Is it possible to add or link PayPal to an account (get from paypal user access token or something like this ) to allow payments without authorization ( without log in and confirmation like with card if we have card number and cvc ) ?

And second question, I am using paypal sandbox and I cannot refresh the token when trying to execute the query

[image]

I get this answer
{
"error": "invalid_refresh_token",
"error_description": "No consent were granted"
}

Its possible they disabled this options on sandbox ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit card company rules do not permit a cvc to be stored under *any* circumstances, so you would never "have" this information. It can only be transmitted when a card is first processed and then must be immediately discarded. As for storing card numbers themselves, there are many rules about that (PCI SAQ-D is a place to start, if you need to research it)

To your PayPal question, to be able to bill a PayPal account without the payer signing in (though they will always have to sign in for initial agreement/set up), the receiving PayPal account must have a feature called "reference transactions". The account owner can contact PayPal's general business support (not technical support) to explain the business need and inquire about being approved for enabling this feature. Once enabled, PayPal can guide you on which API to implement -- be it the older billing agreements API or a newer v2 or v3 vault one.

---

Refresh tokens are used by a Log in with PayPal integration to obtain a new access token when the old one (originally obtained from an authorization_code) is expired. If you are not integrating Log in with PayPal, refresh tokens are not applicable to what you are actually trying to do, and so the request in your screenshot won't be useful to you.

Refresh tokens are not used to obtain a regular REST API access token for authentication, which uses `grant_type=client_credentials` .  If that's what you're actually trying to do, the [documentation is here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/). The public [PayPal Postman API collection sample](https://www.postman.com/paypal) takes care of this step for you, in the collection-level pre-execution script.